# Symfony Role and security explained

Tags: symfony, security, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to learn the Symfony roles and security.  My current **security.yml** file, looks like this:

```
role_hierarchy: 
    ROLE_USER: ROLE_DO_ALMOST_NOTHING
    ROLE_EDITOR: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_EDIT ]
    ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR: [ ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_CONTRIBUTE ]
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR ]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_DO_ANY_THING ]

access_control: 
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin/editor, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/editor, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
    - { path: ^/contributor, roles: ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR }
    - { path: ^/super, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

And I'm using this setup for my users:

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: 
            users:
                person:
                    password: password!
                    roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                admin: 
                    password: password2
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
```

Here is my problem.  I'm been missing around with the access_control portion of security, however, the path `^/admin/editor` with the roles marked as **ROLE_ADMIN** will allow the user person to  access the route even though the person user didn't have the role of **ROLE_ADMIN**.  I was wondering if this is because the route itself is shared by the same controller as the `^admin` route?  Or done someone see where I might have gone wrong with the code, since the user person can access the route that I they shouldn't.

The other routes:

```
- { path: ^/editor, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
- { path: ^/contributor, roles: ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR }
- { path: ^/super, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

Work as expected.

Comment: Hello - did my answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are matching `/admin` before you match `admin/editor`, and that only requires the **ROLE_USER** role.  When you have:

```
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

That matches everything that starts with `/admin`, including `admin/editor`.  As soon as Symfony finds the appropriate route it will not check the first of them. 
 So your `^/admin/editor/` check is never reached.  Try this instead:

```
access_control: 
    - { path: ^/admin/editor, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/editor, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
    - { path: ^/contributor, roles: ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR }
    - { path: ^/super, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

As a good rule of thumb, your most granular/specific routes should be put first.  Any sub-routes should always be put ahead of the main route.

Comment: Yes it did.  Thank you